# About the singularity of $z^{-2}\sin z$ at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

On Priestly's Introduction to Complex Analysis, second edition, at page 206 it says that $z^{-2}\sin z$ has removable singularity at $\infty$. If this is not a typo, what's the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not a typo.** We refer to points at infinite as singularity points on complex analysis, because their substance revolves around a lot of calculations and crucial stuff.

For your specific example, we have the function :

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}\sin(z)$$

The function $f(z)$ has an essential singularity because of $\sin(z)$ which can take infinitely many values at some point $\infty$ due to its periodic nature.

So, the point at $\infty$ acts like a singularity point to your function $z$. More specifically, you'll see about singularities at $\infty$ when you'll be learning about residues (shortly if not already, judging on your "residue-calculus" tag), which are important there. For example, here is a formal statement for a residue at $\infty$ and the condition that shall be met (the singularity at infinity) :

> **Residue at infinity :**
>   $$\text{Res}(f(z),\infty) = -\text{Res}\bigg(\frac{1}{z^2}f\bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg),0\bigg)$$
>   If the condition :
>   $$\lim_{|z| \to \infty}f(z) = 0$$
>   is met, then the residue at infinity can be computed using the following formula :
>   $$\text{Res}(f,\infty)= -\lim_{|z|\to \infty}zf(z)$$
>   If instead :
>   $$\lim_{|z| \to \infty}f(z) = c \neq 0$$
>   then the residue at infinity is :
>   $$\text{Res}(f,\infty)= -\lim_{|z|\to \infty}z^2f'(z)$$

It's also interesting to note, that **every non-constant entire function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ has a singularity at infinity.** Technically, $f$ has a singularity at $\infty$ by virtue of not being defined there.  What is really meant is that a non-constant entire function $f$ has a *non-removable* singularity at $\infty$, and this follows directly from Liouville's theorem: if the singularity at $\infty$ was removable, $f$ would be bounded in a neighbourhood of $\infty$, say $\{z: |z| \ge r\}$, and since $f$ is also bounded on $\{z: |z| \le r\}$ (because a continuous function is bounded on a compact set) $f$ would be bounded on $\mathbb C$, therefore constant by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Great answer +1, mine below seems woefully irrelevant, should I delete?

Comment: @Kevin It's not irrelevant since if you're a student, it's a thing that complicate students, so this example or this answer (as a question) would be met amongst undergraduates. Although now, yes, **it is not a typo** and singularities at infinity are a fact. See also my last part to my answer, which can be indicated on an other way with series expansion (that you also had in your question). Well, that said, you can be your own judge to whether you should delete or not. Thanks a lot for the nice comment by the way, appreciate it !

Comment: Your statement $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(z) = \lim_{z\to \infty}  \frac{1}{z^2}\sin(z)=0$ is wrong, and the (complex) sine is *not* bounded. In particular $f$ *has* an essential singularity at infinity.

Comment: @MartinR I overlooked on that statement, thanks a lot for your heads up!  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

$\sin(z)$ has an essential singularity at infinity (it is periodic so it takes lots of value (in fact all of $\Bbb C$) infinitely often)

Since $z^2$ doesn't have an essential singularity there, $z^{-2}\sin(z)$ also has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Saying what is the typo and what he meant to be writing is hard to tell without more context.